# Role with owner privilege?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql, windows

How can i create new role and provide owner privilege for specific database in SQL Server?

Comment: This will be migrated to ServerFault, please look there for good answers.

Comment: I'd consider this to be an SO question if the OP wants to be able to script permissions.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE ROLE NewRole
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'NewRole'
```